# TastyPie Django: ManyToMany field fails to load

Tags: python, django, django-models, tastypie

So i have this in my models:

```
class narative(models.Model):
    voice = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d',blank = True, null=True)

    def     filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.voice.name)

    def clean(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.voice.name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.filename()


class geolocations(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True,null=True)
    sort = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True,null=True)
    description = HTMLField()
    locations = models.ManyToManyField('locgeo')
    excerpt = models.CharField(max_length=4096)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank = True, null=True)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank = True, null=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('categories',blank = True, null=True)
    photos = models.ManyToManyField('Photo', blank = True, null=True)
    narations = models.ManyToManyField('narative', blank = True, null=True)
```

and then this in my api.py

```
class NarRes(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = narative.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'nar'

class EntryResource(ModelResource):
    locations = fields.ToManyField('self', filter_locations_per_bundle, full=True, null=True)
    locgeo = fields.ToManyField('myapp.api.LocGeoRes', 'locations', full=True, null=True)
    photos = fields.ToManyField('myapp.api.photoResource','photos', full=True, null=True)
    narative = fields.ToManyField('myapp.api.NarRes','narative', full=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = geolocations.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'Locations'
        fields = ['parent','narative','id','name','description','excerpt','lgeo','icon','tags','categories','photos','locations']
```

Problem is, the json output lists the narative as an empty array:

```
...
locations: [ ],
locgeo: [
{
id: 1,
latitude: "33",
longitude: "22",
name: "Location",
radius: 140,
resource_uri: "/api/v1/lgeo/1/"
}
],
name: "Location",
narative: [ ],
photos: [
{
id: 6,
name: "Location",
photo: "/media/uploads/2014/04/18/IMG_1643_result.JPG",
resource_uri: "/api/v1/photos/6/"
},
...
```

When i know for a fact that there is an entry for that record (i can see it when i list the narative resource).

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the model the name of the foreign key is "narations".
In my resource, i was referring to it as "narative".

The modified line should be:

```
narative = fields.ToManyField('myapp.api.NarRes','narations', full=True, null=True)
```

That fixed it.